# Multivariate regression with relationship between outputs

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multivariate-regression

Can anyone suggest some machine learning algorithms for the problem of multi-output regression when the outputs depend both on input vector and other outputs. More specifically, given input vector x and several components of output vector $y = (y_{1},y_{2},\dots,y_{k})$, for example, $(y_{1}, y_{4}, y_{5})$ or even only $(y_{1},y_{2})$, the known indices may differ in different cases. We need to compute the remaining unknown outputs. A real application is electricity load forecasting, the input vector is the information about the household (number of people, number of electric devices, number of rooms, ...) and user inputs the electricity load for one or several months, we want to predict electricity load of unknown months. Two families with the same profile (input vector) may consume different amount of energy.

Comment: Are your outputs categorical or continuous? If they are indeed all categorical then you may use a multiclass model where you would have $k-1$ different models. The other two case: mixed and continuous would are a bit harder. Also you want to make sure that any model your using does not assume that $\vec{Y_1},,..\vec{Y_K}$ are independent.